# MySQL - Is it possible to sort data from one table based on the presence of data in another?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table that I want to be able to sort based on the existence of data in another, related table, but I'm not sure what I want to do is possible in a single query.

For example, say I have a `Products` table and a `Notifications` table. Each table has a bunch of columns, but the important ones for this purpose is an `Active` column, and a foreign key in the `Notifications` table that references the `Products` table. Each row in the `Products` table may be referenced 0 to N times in the `Notifications` table.

```
Products              Notifications
ProductID | Active    NotificationID | ProductID | Active | Type
----------+-------    ---------------+-----------+--------+-----
1         | 1         1              | 2         | 1      | 2
2         | 1         2              | 3         | 0      | 1
3         | 1         3              | 3         | 1      | 1
4         | 1         4              | 5         | 1      | 1
5         | 1         5              | 3         | 1      | 1
```

One use case I'd like to support is to sort the data from the `Products` table based on whether or not there is an active Notification of a particular Type (Type=1) for the Product. So in the above example, Products 3 and 5 to be collated first or last, but all five products should still be in the result set.

I haven't been able to figure out a way to manage this in a single `SELECT` statement. I can easily pull just the Products that do or don't have an active Notification of a certain type, but I can't figure out a way to get them all at once and sort them based on that. Is it possible or do I just need to run a couple of separate queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is accomplished through a `join` and aggregation.  I would suggest summarizing the notifications table as a subquery to get what you want:

```
select p.*
from products p left join
     (select productId, count(*) as cnt
      from notifications n
      where active = 1
      group by productid
     ) n
     on p.productid = n.productid
order by (n.productid is not null) desc;
```

This structure gives you the flexibility of using the existence (as shown above), or the count, or including the count in the `select` list.

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect! I didn't even think to try using a subquery as half of the `JOIN`, but that lets me do exactly what I need.